# How do I JSON serialize an NSDate Dictionary in JSONKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, jsonkit

I tried this using Jsonkit and Apple's JSON serializer with no luck.  It keeps breaking on the geo property, which is an nsarray of NSNumbers.

```
Post* p = [[Post alloc] init];

    p.uname = @"mike";
    p.likes =[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    p.geo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:37.78583], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-122.406417], nil ];
    p.place = @"New York City";
    p.caption = @"A test caption";
    p.date = [NSDate date];


 NSError* error = nil;

    NSString* stuff = [[p getDictionary] JSONStringWithOptions:JKParseOptionNone error:&error];
```

UPDATE: Checking on the error it's the NSDate that it fails on, not the NSArray.  How do I pass in the date formatter into the function?

UPDATE 2: Solved- ok looked at the latest commit for jsonkit and saw that you could do this:

```
 NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];

    NSString* result = [p.dictionary JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone serializeUnsupportedClassesUsingBlock:^id(id object) {
        if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) { return([outputFormatter stringFromDate:object]); }
        return(nil);
    } error:nil];
```

which seems to have worked but note that this feature for JSONKit is WIP so it could change in the next official release.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it keeps breaking"? Is it a crash? Is it not creating JSON strings as you expect? What are you seeing?

Comment: I'd suggest trying to get JSONKit or the JSON serializer in iOS5 working rather than rolling your own parser so to speak. What issues were you having with JSONKit?

Comment: I tried the above code with JSONKit, in returns nil when I call both JSONDATA and JSONString.  If I leave out the NSArray it works fine.  If I serialize just the nsarray it works fine returning the correct serialization... it only seems to be an an issue if I have an nsarray as a value in the nsdictionary and I try to serialize the nsdictionary.

Comment: Are you checking the error returned?

Comment: Show us your `getDictionary` method, and show us what is in `error` after `JSONStringWithOptions:error:` returns.

Comment: I'm guessing that your `Post getDictionary` is broken somehow.

Comment: (You know, of course, you can NSLog an NSDictionary and get a "JSON-like" dump that will show you if there's anything wrong in your setup.  That and the `error` info should nail your problem right away.)

Comment: Ok, I was initially calling it without the parameterless function so forgot about the error... it was the NSDate that it was failing on, not the array.  How do I pass a date formatter to the serializer?

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the "bug" discussion around NSDate support -- https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/52

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmmmm -- can't speak for JSONKit or iOS5 -- I use Stig's [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) framework.  Using it the implementation is fairly succinct:

```
@implementation Post

- (id) initWithName:(NSString*)Name :(NSNumber*)Likes :(NSArray*)Geo :(NSString*)Place :(NSString*)Caption :(NSDate*)Date {

   if ((self=[super init])==nil) {
       return nil;
   }
   uname = Name;
   likes = Likes;
   geo = Geo;
   place = Place;
   caption = Caption;
   date = Date;
   return self;
}

- (NSDictionary*) getAsDictionary {
   NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
   NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
   [dateFormatter release];

   NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:uname,@"uname",
                      likes,@"likes",
                      geo,@"geo",
                      place,@"place",
                      caption,@"caption",
                      dateString,@"date",
                      nil];
   return dict;
}

@end
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Post* post = [[Post alloc] initWithName:@"Mike" 
                                       :[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] 
                                       :[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:37.78583], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-122.406417],nil] 
                                       :@"New York City" :@"A Test caption" 
                                       :[NSDate date]];

    SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
    NSString* json = [writer stringWithObject:[post getAsDictionary]];
    if (json == nil) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@",writer.errorTrace);
    }
    NSLog(@"json = %@",json);
    [writer release];
    [post release];
}
```

produces

> TestJSON[52337:207] json = {"likes":1,"date":"2011-12-13 11:12:57","place":"New York City","caption":"A Test caption","uname":"Mike","geo":[37.78583,-122.4064]}

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't notice, the dateFormatter format is not correct. Minutes are defined using 'mm', not 'MM'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to multiply the number of seconds by 1000 to get the correct long number to send to your server side (or whatever).

```
[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[yourDate timeIntervalSince1970]*1000]
```

Example :

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:uname,@"uname",
                      likes,@"likes",
                      geo,@"geo",
                      place,@"place",
                      caption,@"caption",
                      [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[yourDate timeIntervalSince1970]*1000],@"date",
                      nil];
```

Comment: only if your server is expecting milliseconds