# Converting a Dictionary holding dates to JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdate

I have a fairly large and complex `NSManagedObject` that I'm manipulating within my application and sending back to a server as JSON. My plan was to do what I need to do in my application, convert the object to a Dictionary, and then send it along after calling `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject` (I've also tried using `SwiftyJSON`, which I think is doing more or less the same thing). This was all working fine until I needed to include some dates.

Basically all of the documentation I've seen says that serialization works just fine with a certain list of object types, which does not include `NSDate`. Sadly, I need some dates. I should note that I am working with a dictionary of dictionaries that may have dates scattered all up and down the tree, so if I recursively run through to convert them all to strings I'm going to have to do a whole lot of copying to `NSMutable` dictionaries. Surely there's an easier way? I'm a bit new to Swift and iOS development and I can't help feeling like I'm either doing something wrong or that there is a built-in solution to this problem that I'm just missing. I can't be the first person who wants to send back a date as JSON. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494149/how-do-i-json-serialize-an-nsdate-dictionary-in-jsonkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization) says;

> You use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation
>   objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.
>
> An object that may be converted to JSON **must have** the following
>   properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
>
> All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
>   NSDictionary, or NSNull.
>
> All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
>
> Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
>
> Other rules may apply. Calling **isValidJSONObject:** or attempting a
>   conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be
>   converted to JSON data.

I think you should convert your dates to String and add them to your Dictionary. But it says; Other rules may apply. Calling **isValidJSONObject:** Just try to create a dictionary with your NSDate object and call the isValidJSONObject if it returns true it should be work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's not that a big of a deal to convert the dates, but I really wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way around.

Comment: Try to use isValidJSONObject with your NSDate Dictionary. I am really wondering too.